# condition to define an distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

i have a question please. What's the necessary and sufficient condition of the sequences $(a_n)$ for $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^\star} a_n \varphi(\frac{1}{n})$ be finite? When $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: no i have no idea

Comment: can you answer simpler questions like when is $∑a_n\phi(1/n)$ finite?

Comment: i edit my question, thank you for the suggest

Comment: Do you have any idea about how $\varphi$ might behave close to $0$?

Comment: no we search a condition for $\varphi$

Comment: We don't search a condition for $\varphi,$ but still it's useful. We can write $\varphi(x) = \varphi(0) + O(x)$ so $\varphi(\frac1n) = \varphi(0) + O(\frac1n).$ Generally, $\varphi(0) \neq 0,$ so $\sum_n a_n \varphi(\frac1n) = \left(\sum_n a_n\right) \varphi(0) + \sum_n a_n O(\frac1n).$ When is the first term finite?